# How to cast an object to any type using object.GetType()

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, dynamic-cast, targettype

I have an `object` type variable where I want to cast it to its original data type. Data type could be anything (int, enum, class, etc)

`(object.GetType())object` is not working

Edited:

The reason I want to cast it again to original, because I'm building a cosmos db query with multiple parameters

I have a method `QueryCosmos(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)` where key is the field name in cosmos, and value is the value of the field that matches the condition (it could be any data type).

```
static string QueryCosmos(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
   var sb = new StringBuilder($"SELECT * FROM c WHERE ");
   foreach (var p in parameters)
   {
      if (!(p.Value is string))
      {
         // this handles non-string data types
         var value = p.Value == null ? "null" : p.Value.ToString().ToLower();  
         sb.Append($"c.{p.Key} = {value} and ");
      }
      else
      {
         sb.Append($"c.{p.Key} = '{p.Value}' and ");
      }
   }
   return sb.ToString().Substring(0, sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(" and "));
}
```

My issue is with this line of code `var value = p.Value == null ? "null" : p.Value.ToString().ToLower();`

If I pass on an `enum` type, doesn't match the data in cosmos. Because in cosmos, this is stored as the numeric value of the enum. I would need it to convert to its `numeric` value. There are multiple possible `enum` types that can be passed. That's the reason why I wanted a dynamic way to covert to original data type

Hope this clears up the concern

Comment: You likely have an X/Y Problem. You should never need to up-cast from `Object` in C#/.NET. Please post all of the code relevant to this problem.

Comment: "I want to cast it to its original data type." - **why do you want to do this?** How will your program _actually take advantage_ of knowing what the runtime type of the object is?

Comment: So even if you could do this, how are you going to use it or program against it at design time? The IDE cant read your mind (in the future)

Comment: Maybe if you could explain what problem you are trying to solve, we could give you concrete solutions that would help

Comment: @Dai I edited the post to give you more context

Comment: @TheGeneral I edited the post to give you more context

Comment: I am *sure* that cosmos has native support for parameters, no need to mangle everything into a string.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If they're using the original Azure Table Storage client library... you'd be surprised how aneamic it was.

Comment: @chary Exactly which Azure CosmosDB client library are you using? (NuGet packageId and version)

Comment: @chary **Your `QueryCosmos` method is vulnerable to SQL-injection**. That is a major security issue.

Comment: The basic question here seems to be: "How to cast an enum to an int, without knowing the explicit type of enum?".

Comment: @chary Please confirm that `QueryDefinition.WithParameter` does not handle your `enum` values correctly, as it looks to me like it should. If you aren't using `QueryDefinition.WithParameter` then you should.

Comment: @chary I've updated my answer so that it handles `Enum` values (including all sizes of `enum`).

Answer (score 2):

As you're targeting Azure CosmosDB, you don't need to write your own query-generator, [the CosmosDB client library (`Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos`) has one built-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-dotnet-v3sdk-samples#query-examples).

In your case, [use `QueryDefinition` and `WithParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.querydefinition?view=azure-dotnet) to build a strongly-typed query. The `WithParameter` method accepts values as `object` and it handles type-specific logic for you.

As you are using a dynamic-query my code below shows how you can *safely* build a query's `WHERE` clause from a dictionary by using named-parameters.

**Never embed query parameter values directly in the query SQL itself** because doing so opens yourself up to SQL injection *which is a very bad thing*.

---

#### Update for `enum`:

<sub>I'll admit that I'm unfamiliar with the Azure CosmosDB client library, though I did take a quick look at the documentation and poked around the library in ILSpy.</sub>

As for handling `enum` values: the `QueryDefinition.WithParameter` method should handle `enum` values correctly as it preserves the boxed enum values in its `.Value` property.

If it doesn't, then converting any `enum` to an `Int32` can be done like so - albeit with boxing (while it *is* possible to cast *any* enum to `Int64` without casting that requires runtime IL emit which is beyond the scope of this answer, [but I have an implementation in my GitHub Gists](https://gist.github.com/Jehoel/aa07ceda23b2ca03184722c3f63ce7ca) if you're interested):

I've updated the code below to use this `foreach` loop which checks for `Enum` (which matches *any* and *all* `enum` types, regardless of their underlying-type, though this example will fail if you have any `enum : Int64` enums with values outside `Int32`'s range - but that's trivial to fix and so is left as an exercise for the reader).

```
    foreach( var kvp in parameters )
    {
        if( kvp.Value is Enum e )
        {
            Int32 enumAsInt32 = (Int32)Convert.ChangeType( e, TypeCode.Int32 );
            query = query.WithParameter( kvp.Key, enumAsInt32 );
        }
        else
        {
            query = query.WithParameter( kvp.Key, kvp.Value );
        }
    }
```

---

### The rest of my original answer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

//


public static QueryDefinition BuildCosmosQuery( Dictionary<String,Object> parameters )
{
    String sqlText = "SELECT * FROM foobar AS f WHERE " + GetWhereClauses( "f", parameters.Keys );

    QueryDefinition query = new QueryDefinition( sqlText );
    foreach( var kvp in parameters )
    {
        if( kvp.Value is Enum e )
        {
            Int32 enumAsInt32 = (Int32)Convert.ChangeType( e, TypeCode.Int32 );
            query = query.WithParameter( kvp.Key, enumAsInt32 );
        }
        else
        {
            query = query.WithParameter( kvp.Key, kvp.Value );
        }
    }
    
    return query;
}

private static String GetWhereClauses( String tableAlias, IEnumerable<String> parameterNames )
{
    return parameterNames
        .Select( pn => "{0}.{1} = @{1}".FmtInv( tableAlias, pn ) )
        .StringJoin( separator: " AND " );
}

//

public static class Extensions
{
    public static String StringJoin( this IEnumerable<String> source, String separator )
    {
        return String.Join( values: source, separator: separator ); 
    }

    public static String FmtInv( this String format, params Object[] args )
    {
        return String.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, args: args );
    }
}
```

[See the `QueryWithSqlParameters` method in this code sample to see how to use `QueryDefinition`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/Queries/Program.cs#L189-L212).

Answer (score 1):

I've not looked at your new edit, but hopefully my answer is still relevant.

If you wish to cast an instance to its known concrete class type then you could use the `as` operator.

Here's some example code:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    public class BaseClass{
        public string Base="BaseClass";
    }
    public class Class1:BaseClass{
        public string Value="Class 1";
    }
    public class Class2:BaseClass{
        public string Value="Class 2";
        public string AnotherValue="Another value";
    }
    
    static void Main()
    {
        List<BaseClass> list=new List<BaseClass>(){new Class1(), new Class2()};
        
        foreach( var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Item.Base = {item.Base}");
            if(typeof(Class1).IsAssignableFrom( item.GetType() ))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Item.Value = {(item as Class1).Value}");
            }
            if(typeof(Class2).IsAssignableFrom( item.GetType() ))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Item.Value = {(item as Class2).Value}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Item.Value = {(item as Class2).AnotherValue}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you the output of:

```
Item.Base = BaseClass
Item.Value = Class 1
Item.Base = BaseClass
Item.Value = Class 2
Item.Value = Another value
```

Comment: Consider using `typeof(Class1).IsAssignableFrom( item.GetType() )` instead of `item.GetType() == typeof(Class1)` - that way you can handle non-`sealed` type hierarchies.

Comment: @Dai - good point, thank you - I've updated my answer accordingly